# Parsing date Time return Invalid Date

Tags: date-fns

I'm trying parse this date `2021-07-08T08:45:00+0300`, but it return `Invalid Date` and i want to get `2021 July 8 8:45`

```
import { parseISO } from 'date-fns'
const dateTime = '2021-07-08T08:45:00+0300'
parseISO(dateTime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will cause invalid date because the given date is invalid ISO format you could make it ISO.

```
import { parseISO } from 'date-fns'
const parseDate = parseISO(new Date('2021-07-08T08:45:00+0300').toISOString())
```

And it should work